# QGIS Query Builder - Syntax for filtering records across multiple fields

Tags: sql, database, gis, qgis

I am trying to create a filter in QGIS which only shows records that satisfy two unique fields. An example is wanting to display records which are 'animals' and the species of the animal as an 'eagle'. I have tried using an AND operator without success, I can't seem to get the syntax right. Please be kind as I am new to SQL!
So far I have tried the following without success:

"KINGDOM" = 'Animalia' AND "SPECIES_NAME" = 'Eagle'

Comment: The syntax seems correct. Anyway consider that "the filter is made at the data provider (OGR, PostgreSQL, MSSQL…) level. So the syntax depends on the data provider."
Maybe the issue depends in the specific layer type and data provider.
Have you tried to use a single field filter with success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my syntax was correct but since my layer was in edit mode the query builder would not accept it. For other QGIS dummies like myself, make sure your layer is not in edit mode before querying!